# sharing variables between powershell and C#

Tags: c#, scripting, powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to build a document assembly application in .Net that will allow rules and conditions to be embedded within the document fragments, presumably using some kind of scripting language (and I don't really want to invent my own scripting language)

I need the ability for the c# code to invoke the scripting language and vice versa, but importantly I also want them to be able to share arbitrary data structures by reference (not just passing a couple of strings back and forward by value)

Can I do this with powershell or do I need to use a DLR language such as IronPython? Come to that, are there other advantages of using a DLR language which mean I should use DLR anyway?

Andy

Comment: any solution with full source code about it ?

Answer (score 2):

I think [this article](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/HowToRunPowerShell.aspx) is exactly what you're looking for (for Powershell, anyway).

Using a DLR language might bring the bits of code you'll be executing a little bit closer to home. Invoking Powershell from a .NET app executes on a new thread according to the above article.

In any case, I would personally be leery of executing random bits of any scripting language without defining a subset of allowed commands and validating the input against that.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell can instantiate and use C# (or any .NET) objects just fine.  I've never tried having C# code invoke powershell commands, but I'd be surprised if it couldn't.  That said, the DLR route is good too, and in fact there's examples in Ayende's DSL book [http://www.amazon.com/DSLs-Boo-Domain-Specific-Languages/dp/1933988606/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1308063119&sr=8-1](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1933988606) that might be useful to you as well (even if you end up not using Boo, it's a good read).